# How to get Magento 2 Customer before and after edit Customer data?

Tags: magento2, customer, event-observer

I want to implement erp system in my Magento 2.3.4 website, i need to check whether customer has changed his name or dob, if the customer changed it , i need to send the updated data to the erp system, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think to use the Event to send the updated data to the ERP system.

check below `event` I hope this helps to complete this functionality.

**Event name:** `customer_account_edited`

File: vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/EditPost.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
        'customer_account_edited',
        ['email' => $customerCandidateDataObject->getEmail()]
    );
```

Another

you can try this event: `customer_save_after_data_object` and `customer_address_save_after`, `customer_address_save_before` if above event is not work then try this event.

Comment: how can i check if the email, name and dob has been changed using those observer? as i know that observer only attach the customer email

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can try to implement one by one the above observers to achieve this functionality